# Datatable extend excel option doesn't work with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, excel, datatables

In the reference [here](http://live.datatables.net/jijumeji/1/edit), I have the datatable with excel export customization to print with cell colors. It works fine when the  `paging: false,` . With paging,export excel with cell color is incomplete. How to make it work with paging ?

Comment: If this has been solved, please update... and post how you got the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by this using `var colour = $(table.cell(':eq('+count+')',2).node()).css('background-color');` instead of

```
var colour = $('tbody tr:eq('+parseInt(count)+') td:eq(2)').css('background-color');
```

reference [here](http://live.datatables.net/horuxuxo/2/edit)

Answer (score 1):

upon building the excel, I noticed that you used to color cells in excel file by checking the css attribute color that if it's color is red you will color it in excel red also.

It works all well with your **paging:false** because all the cells that needs color has already been colored since all of it is displayed in one page while if your **paging:true**, the cells that has color in excel are only those cells that has been displayed in front page and has already been filled with color, and those that needs color that was not displayed or in other page number does not have color in excel, because it was not displayed in front and is not being colored.

so my solution for that is that to have the same condition from rowCallback inside the customized function in creating excel. please see below:

```
$('row c[r^="C"]', sheet).each( function (data, info) {
          console.log(info.textContent); 
          if (skippedHeader) {



            var txt = info.textContent; 
            if (txt === 'London') {
              $(this).attr( 's', '35' );
            }
            else if (txt === 'New York') {
              $(this).attr( 's', '40' );
            }

            count++;
          }
          else {
            skippedHeader = true;
          }
        });
```

you may also check the link: http://live.datatables.net/jijumeji/105/edit

Comment: I tried that approach as well even before you post this answer.It still doesn't work when the pagination is true.  You may remove the line  paging: false, and see.

Comment: I have edited the customized function, please see on your end

Answer (score -1):

You have to use manual render for excel and pdf export.

I think, automatic render useless.

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/exportButtons